# Error: 0 - Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: joomla-3.x

My Joomla site breaks after I attempt to login in the front-end, returning an Error.

Error: 0 - Call to a member function get() on null

[image: printscreen]

I can´t see anything in the console, I dont have any further information where the error come from.
This happens after I restored my site with Akeeba backup, everything was fine until the restore. I tried to restore other older backups but the issue still the same.
I have checked the log and tmp path and they are ok, the folders and files permissions are ok to, at last I have repaired the DB in the Cpanel but the problem persists. I dont know what to do more.
The weird thing is that I still can make the login in the back-end without no problems. I´m confused. I dont have 50$ to buy a subscription in Akeeba, so i use the free version, thats why I need some help, because akeeba only give assistance to the pro version. I have joomla 3 running in php 7.0.9 version

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Akeeba developer?

Comment: They only respond to those who have a paid subscription. And even these, they are slow to respond. still I do not have access to the Akeeba developer email.

Comment: https://www.akeebabackup.com/contact-us.html

Comment: Was this a restore to the same location where the website was working before or a restore to a new location? Maybe try switching back to PHP 5.6 or similar to see if the issue persists. Update all third party extensions to the latest versions. Check whether all third party extensions are PHP 7 compatible: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJj02l3ByBvJF-Q67XXuGmrFvS8iIBEnDEcVcmwqzLc/edit?pref=2&pli=1#gid=0

Comment: Yes! I did that, problem solved. I change the PHP 7 to 5.6 and everything is ok now.

Comment: @NeilRobertson - since your comment gave the solution to the OP, add this as an answer below. Inform here to upvote it when done. And is this Google Doc, a list that you created and maintain?

Comment: Downgrading should never be accepted as a solution.

Comment: I agree with @SteffenNielsen that downgrading PHP to an older version is a fault finding step rather than a permanent solution and have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that you have an extension that is not compatible with PHP 7 yet.

I recommend:

- temporarily switching back to PHP 5.6
- upgrading all third party extensions to the latest versions

See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJj02l3ByBvJF-Q67XXuGmrFvS8iIBEnDEcVcmwqzLc/edit?pref=2&pli=1#gid=0 for which extensions are compatible with PHP 7.0.

As far as I am aware, this document was created by [Radek Suski](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/1550/radek-suski).

Once everything is working again, switch back to [a supported version of PHP](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).